# Project has been created twice on gitlab.com

Tags: project, gitlab

A project has been created twice on gitlab.com ...

Maybe this issue has been the reason:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15

I've deleted the project, but the other one still exists in the list:

Since this, http://gitlab.com/ and the project home show an error 500. (http://github.com/username/projectname)

How can I remove the deleted project finally?

Comment: What is this url "http://github.com/username/projectname"?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/lazytyper/myself

Comment: Use the API to delete the project? https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/